# GLES10.glGetIntegerv returns 0 on Samsung device

Tags: android, opengl-es, samsung-mobile

I use the code down below to determine the maximum width and height for my bitmaps in my drawView method. On most devices this works just fine and returns 2048 or 1024 but on the Samsung S3 I'm currently testing, it returns 0.
Did I do something wrong or do I have to find a workaround for Samsung devices?

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GLES10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
Log.d("GLES10", "max: " + String.valueOf(maxSize[0]));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the root of the problem! I didn't add the hardwareAccelerated="true" tag in the manifest, so it only worked on devices which have this set to true by default.

```
<application
    ...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>
```